# Match two strings regardless of whitespace in perl

Tags: regex, perl

How can I, given two variables, match a two strings regardless of white spaces?

```
my $String_1 = "FOO BAR";
my $String_2 = "FOOBAR";

if ($String_1 =~ m/ WHAT GOES HERE? /) {
    print "Match\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is neatly done using the *translate* operator with the *non-destructive* option `tr///r`.

This program encapsulates the comparison in a subroutine `no_space_compare`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;     # For non-destructive translate

my $string_1 = "FOO BAR";
my $string_2 = "FOOBAR";

say $string_1 eq $string_2 ? 'match' : 'no match';

say no_space_compare($string_1, $string_2) ? 'match' : 'no match';

sub no_space_compare {
  my ($s1, $s2) = @_;
  $s1 =~ tr/ //dr eq $s2 =~ tr/ //dr;
}
```

**output**

```
no match
match
```

Comment: space isn't the only whitespace

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all whitespace from both of the strings and check if they are equal.

```
my $String_1 = "FOO BAR";
my $String_2 = "FOOBAR";
my $temp1 = $String_1;
my $temp2 = $String_2;
$temp1 =~ s/\s+//g;
$temp2 =~ s/\s+//g;

if ($temp1 eq $temp2) {
    print "Match\n";
} else {
    print "No match\n";
}
```

Here I assigned them to temporary variables to preserve the whitespace in the original string, but you don't have to do that.

---

edit: Here's a way to do it with just one temporary variable. The regex flag `/x` means ignore white space. However you still need a temporary variable to remove white space from the other string.

```
my $String_1 = "FOO BAR";
my $String_2 = "FOO BAR";
my $temp = $String_2;
$temp =~ s/\s+//g;
if ( $temp =~ m/^$String_1$/x) {
    print "Match\n";
} else {
    print "No match\n";
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it in one line? I would like to avoid storing  a temporary variable.

Comment: perl has (since 5.14) an /r flag that returns the result of substitution.  use it to avoid temporary variables

Answer (score 1):

An alternative one-liner without using a variable would be

```
print "match\n" if join("", split(/\s+/, $String_1) ) eq join("", split(/\s+/, $String_2) );
```

or, if you want to see no match for no match

```
my $match = join("", split(/\s+/, $String_1) ) eq join("", split(/\s+/, $String_2) );
print $match ? "match\n" : "no match\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the whitespace just for the test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

my $string_a = 'F  O O BA   R' ;
my $string_b = ' F O     O  B    A  R        ' ;

if( ( $string_a =~ s! !!gr ) eq ( $string_b =~ s! !!gr ) ) {
  printf "Yes, '%s' and '%s' are equal.\n" , $string_a , $string_b ;
}
```

This will print:

`Yes, 'F  O O BA   R' and ' F O     O  B    A  R        ' are equal.`

The `r` modifier of the regex returns the modified string.

Comment: What version of perl are you using? I tried this and got `Bareword found where operator expected at main.pl line 9, near "s! !!gr"
syntax error at main.pl line 9, near "s! !!gr "` on here: http://www.compileonline.com/execute_perl_online.php

Comment: oh they are running `5.10`. The `r` was probably added in 5.12 or 5.14 or something.

Comment: It was added with `5.14`. See [Changelog 5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Regular-Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
my @str = ("F OO BA     R", " FO OB   AR");

print (($str[0] =~ s/\s*//gr eq $str[1] =~ s/\s*//gr)?'Match':'No Match');
```